# WordPress wp query LIKE statement

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I implement LIKE %x, %x%, x% with my custom wp_query args

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    query_posts(array('post_type'=>'photo')); 
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'layzend_posts_where', 10, 2 );
    function layzend_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query )
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $term = $_GET['term'] ? $_GET['term'] : '';
        $type = $_GET['type'] ? $_GET['type'] : '';
        if ( !empty($term) ) 
        {
            switch ($type)
            {
                case 'all':
                    $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) ) . '%\'';
                    break;
                case 'any':
                    $terms = explode(' ', $term);
                    $where .= ' AND ';

                    foreach ($terms as $t)
                    {
                        $whereed[] = $wpdb->posts . ".post_title LIKE '%$t%' ";
                    }

                    $where .= '(' . implode(' OR ',$whereed) . ')';

                    break;
                case 'id':
                    $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID = \'' . esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) ) . '\'';
                    break;
                case 'exact':
                    $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title = \'' . esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) ) . '\'';
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $where;
    }
    ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php
    $paged = get_url_var('page');
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'photo',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'orderby'=> 'post_date',
        '' => '',
        'paged'=>$paged
    ));
```

Comment: For better understanding vide wordpress query filter. where you can attach various filter with your query to produce more complex sql query.